# Calculate incidence density/ rate after weighting

Tags: r, survival, propensity-scores, epidemiology

How to calculate an incidence density/ rate for weighted data, e.g. using weighting methods such as matching weights, IPW, ...?

-- UPDATE 06.11.2023:
Regard the following [paper](https://www.antonpottegaard.dk/publications/originalarticles/%5Bo227%5D%20-%20Use%20of%20dipeptidyl%20peptidase-4%20inhibitors%20and%20risk%20of%20splanchnic%20vein%20thrombosis.pdf) as an example of incidence density/ rate calculation:
In Table 2 the crude and weighted incidence density/ rate is given as:

`Events / Follow-up, person-years` per 1000 person-years.

Thus, the crude incidence density/ rate for DPP-4 inhibitors is:
`58 / 265 553 * 1000` which results in: `0.22` (rounded to the second).

Lets move on to example data with follow-up time in days:

```
library(cobalt)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
lalonde <- cbind(lalonde,
                 event = sample(c(0,1), size=614, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.84,0.16)),
                 time = runif(614, min=10, max=365))

formula <- treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75 + re78

# PS
lalonde$pscore <- glm(formula, data = lalonde,
                  family = binomial(link = "logit"))$fitted.values

# Calculate weights
lalonde$weight <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1,
                         pmin(lalonde$pscore, 1 - lalonde$pscore) / lalonde$pscore,
                     pmin(lalonde$pscore, 1 - lalonde$pscore) / (1 - lalonde$pscore))
```

Here, the calculation of a crude incidence density/ rate for the treated per 1000 person-years is given:

```
crude <- lalonde %>%
  filter(treat == 1) %>%
  summarize(event = sum(event == 1),
            persontime = sum(time) / 365.25)

crude %>% 
  summarize(Incidence_density = round(event / persontime * 1000, 1))
```

resulting in:

```
  Incidence_density
1             294.5
```

When using weighted data to calculate the incidence density/ rate for the treated we have to keep in mind the **weighted** events and **weighted** person-time:

`weighted.event`:
The number of events is the sum of the weights for the individuals who had events and were treated.

`weighted.persontime`:
Person time is the sum of the weights  times the person time for those who were treated.

So its just: `weighted.event / weighted.persontime`

Thus:

```
weighted <- lalonde %>%
  filter(treat == 1) %>%
  summarize(weighted.event = sum(weight * event),
            weighted.persontime = sum(weight * time) / 365.25)

weighted %>% 
  summarize(Incidence_density = round(weighted.event / weighted.persontime * 1000, 1))
```

which gives:

```
  Incidence_density
1             269.6
```

Is there a reference for the methodology? I do not find any explanation of that.
Further, calculating the weighted incidence density/ rate may need robust standard errors to calculate the CI.
In addition, I am not aware of any package that can perform these calculations.

Thank you

Comment: It might just be me, but I'm having trouble grasping what you mean by "an incidence density in a weighted sample." Please edit the question to provide a more concrete example of what you are trying to estimate, preferably based on the specific study you are performing. Some sample data and a comparison between results with IPTW and matching weights could help a lot.

Comment: @EdM I have updated my question.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some references to the formula you are using, such the formula you use to create weights and the weighted incidence? It's just have not used those definitions before.

Comment: @jmarkov For matching weights see https://doi.org/10.37737/ace.22013  For the weighted incidence density i have no reference. That’s what i’m asking for, but i don't know how else to calculate this, since the weights have to be included?!

Comment: Ok I see! Where did you find this weighted incidence density then? I mean, you want to calculate it, but it might not even exist...

Comment: @jmarkov e.g. doi.org/10.1161/CIRCULATIONAHA.122.060687  See Table2. Description in statistical analysis: "...incidence rate of clinical outcomes over time ... presented as the total number of outcomes of interest per 100 person-years."

Comment: Sorry, I opened the paper but I cannot find the expression "weighted incidence density"! Regarding the sentence the "incidence rate ... over time" it should be just a normal incidence rate as incidences can only be calculated over time and not cross sectionally (that would be a prevalence). In my opionion you are misinterpreting some things of how propensity score/ inverse probability weighting works. I will try to answer your question pointing out the mistakes, but I will need some time.

Comment: @jmarkov Thank you very much! No. the authors give the incidence rate/density in table 2 as IR/100 PY (IPTW) - so they accounted for the weighting.

Comment: @jmarkov Here 10.1111/dom.14253 the authors have used the term (weighted) incidence rate in the Analyses section. I believe my approach is correct, but I cannot find a reference regarding the methodology. Next question will be how to obtain robust SE for CI. I am not aware of any package included such function.

Comment: You can retrieve the paper here: https://www.antonpottegaard.dk/publications/originalarticles/%5Bo227%5D%20-%20Use%20of%20dipeptidyl%20peptidase-4%20inhibitors%20and%20risk%20of%20splanchnic%20vein%20thrombosis.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `survey` package can do these weighted calculations (conditional outcome probability weights work the same way as sampling weights)

```
> d<-svydesign(id=~1, weights=~weight, data=lalonde)
> d<-update(d, time_kyr=time/365.25/1000)
> svyratio(~event,~I(time_kyr),design=d)
Ratio estimator: svyratio.survey.design2(~event, ~I(time_kyr), design = d)
Ratios=
      I(time_kyr)
event    270.0646
SEs=
      I(time_kyr)
event    40.04273
```

Or, if you prefer, estimate the totals with standard errors and do the division

```
> totals<-svytotal(~event+time_kyr,design=d)
> totals
            total     SE
event    29.88659 4.3266
time_kyr  0.11066 0.0059
> svycontrast(totals, quote(event/time_kyr))
          nlcon     SE
contrast 270.06 40.043
```

Ratio estimation is classical in survey sampling; the formulas will be in any survey sampling textbook.